# How to change cursor into a circle in JavafX?

Tags: javafx, cursor

I want to make the cursor be a circle, without fill(something like the brush in Photoshop), but I only found just a way to put an image on the cursor, nothing with a shape.

Answer (score 1):

You can use node snapshot to do that:

```
// create any shape you want (e.g. circle)
// set fill to null
Circle circle = new Circle(32, null);

// set stroke to required color
circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

// this is needed to 'cut' the fill from snapshot
SnapshotParameters sp = new SnapshotParameters();
sp.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

// perform snapshot of the shape into an image
Image image = circle.snapshot(sp, null);

// set cursor from that image
scene.setCursor(new ImageCursor(image, 16, 16));
```